# Android Locale.US code resetting to normal font when we need small

Tags: android, android-layout

Edited:

A few days ago I posted a question on how to make the tablet look like Locale.US for everything from string conversions, numbers, editText input, etc.  I was given this code to put in onCreate:

```
    Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = Locale.US;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

I found that the font scaling was working on some devices (Nexus-4) but was not working on other devices (Nexus-7, Nexus-S).  My application needs to have font scaling to work across the range of devices so this was a big problem.   I guessed that the problem was that the font scale factor was not being read for all devices so that when I wrote the new configuration, it would overwrite the font scaling on these devices.  I found that this could be explicitly read and added two lines to read the font scaling and write it as part of my new configuration.  This solved my problem before anyone commented here on SO but I thought someone else might have this problem so I am updating my question to this solution.  the code added is this:

```
    float scale = getResources().getConfiguration().fontScale;
    config.fontScale = scale;
```